# Not able to upload package in https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have gone through already available answers in SO but nothing seems working for me.

I am following python commands to upload my package(Note: I am a new user and have registered the account with username and password):

**Create setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='',  # This is the name of your PyPI-package.
    version='0.1',  # Update the version number for new releases
    scripts=['']  # The name of your script, and also the command you'll be using for calling it
)
```

**Package the script:**

```
python setup.py sdist
```

**Register the account:**

```
python setup.py register
```

This prompted me below message(I choose 2nd as I am new user):

```
1. use your existing login,
2. register as a new user,
3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:
```

**Upload the package:**

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

**After trying steps I got the error while uploading:**

```
Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
```

Comment: did you try another option, e.g. register for an account at https://pypi.org/ and then choose option 1 when prompted?

Comment: @HaleemurAli: I tried that. Do you have any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the python and pip version you are using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: It's 9.0.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found the simple solution. Also, @hoefling answer helps me to solve them.

Register as a user in https://pypi.org/ and use register account command which mentioned in the question.

Now, Three magic steps which will resolve the issue.

```
pip install twine

python setup.py sdist

# This will ask for you username and password
twine upload dist/*
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to upgrade your package, just follow the below simple steps:

1. Delete the `build`, `dist`, and `<package name>.egg-info` folders in your root directory.
2. Change the version number in your `setup.py` file.
3. Create distribution again. e.g: `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
4. Upload distribution again. e.g: `twine upload dist/*`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, note that `register` is deprecated and not necessary anymore. When trying to register a package on PyPI, you should get a message:

```
Server response (410): This API is no longer supported, instead simply upload the file.
```

Just skip the register step and proceed with the uploading.

#### `distutils`/`setuptools`

Create a file `$HOME/.pypirc` with the contents:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
username: <username>
password: <password>
```

and repeat the upload:

```
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

Thing is, the `distutils`' `upload` subcommand doesn't provide an option to enter the credentials from command line, instead completely relying on the `.pypirc` file.

#### `twine`

If storing credentials in plain text format is not your thing, `twine` provides a possibility of entering credentials from command line. [This is also the officially recommended tool for uploading packages.](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#upload-your-distributions)

1. Install `twine`:

   ```
   $ pip install twine
   ```
2. Build the package:

   ```
   $ python setup.py clean sdist
   ```
3. Upload:

   ```
   $ twine upload dist/*
   ```

   The tool will ask you for the username and password.

`twine` also lets you provide the credentials in environment variables:

```
$ TWINE_USERNAME=me TWINE_PASSWORD=passwd twine upload dist/*
```

or [via keyring](https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#keyring-support).

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in home dir by `touch ~/.pypirc` similar look like: added pytest optionally

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=your_password
```

## Things to care about the following error

> 403: Invalid or non-existent authentication information

- If there is a `%` in your password just type it without escaping; e.g. `Hello%123`
- If there is a space character in your password just type it without quotes; e.g. `Hello 123`

## Register your package against PyPI's server

```
python setup.py register -r pypi
```

## Upload your package

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
```

From official [doc](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/)

First, you need a PyPI user [account](https://pypi.org/account/register/)

Comment: where to  create .pypirc file

Comment: touch ~/.pypirc

Answer (score 2):

To change to the new PyPI authentication method, go to https://pypi.org/manage/account/token/

Login to your account and you'll see

[image]

Give the token a name, select the Scope (i.e. what repository do you allow the Token to be used for).

Then copy the token as the password in your `~/.pypirc` file, use `__token__` as the username, e.g.

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    testpypi

[pypi]
username: __token__
password: pypi-12837192048i1234...
```